# Add variable to isolate scope from directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm attempting to set up localization on my site using a directive. Unfortunately I'm hitting a snag when I attempt to pluralize a string.

I'm attempting to add a 'translation' variable to the isolate scope of an element, but when I instruct ngPluralize to use when='translation' (in the html) nothing happens. When debugging it appears that scope.translation is set, but something isn't happening to allow ngPluralize to use it. I've tried:

```
scope.$eval(function(scope){scope.translation = value});
```

and a few other variations.

Here is an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Yj1Kevdiqkug7aNJ8IyD

Comment: I am also trying to do the same but as u mentioned, the when = "translations" is not getting updated. Did you get any luck with your approach is there an alternative to do it. You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21489657/ng-pluralize-with-translations-errortypeerror for more details

Answer (score 0):

If you wish your directive can change the value of the scope of the element, and not a scope specific to the directive, you must simply not use an isolated scope. Just remove the line `scope : {}`.

Comment: I've tried that and there is still an issue with ngPluralize not being able to see the value that is passed in the when attribute. Ideally, however, I would have an individual scope for each element. I would rather reference the translation on the html page like this:
    <div ... when="translation">
rather than
    <div ... when="translation['path.to.string.]>