# ng-pluralize with translations Error:"TypeError"

Tags: angularjs, localization, angularjs-directive, pluralize

Hi I am trying to localize the strings for pluralization in Angular. I am using ng-pluralize directive to handle pluralization and for localizations I am passing the strings to the directive at runtime based on user locale. But I am getting error "TypeError: Object # has no method 'one'" even if the $scope is loaded with translated strings.Following is my html code,

```
 <input class="input-text" type="number" ng-model="candyCount" ng-keypress="loadStrings()"/>
 <ng-pluralize count = "candyCount" when = "translateStrings" ></ng-pluralize>
```

Javascript code

```
   myApp.controller(‘MyCtrl’,function($scope){

   $scope.loadStrings = function(){ 

        $scope.translateStrings = null;

          if (userLocale == "en-us"){
                 $scope.translateStrings = 
                   {'0': '0 candy for sale','one': '1 candy for sale.','other': '{} candies for sale.'} ;
              debugger;
              }
             else if (userLocale == "de-de"){
                   $scope.translateStrings = {'0': '0 Süßigkeiten ausgewählt',
                   'one': '1 Süßigkeiten zum Verkauf',
                'other': '{} Süßigkeiten zum Verkauf.'
               };
             debugger;
           }

        }

    });
```

I have added debugger to every condition block, so when I check for $scope.translateStrings in the console, I get output as,
For en-us:

```
   $scope.translateStrings
   {'0': '0 candy for sale','one': '1 candy for sale.','other': '{} candies for sale.'}
```

Is it because the directive is not getting updated with the latest strings, or am I going wrong somewhere.

Comment: So basically your code is populating the "translateStrings" with the object, but still you are getting error as "when" condition in ng-pluralize is not getting updated.

Comment: Yes the $scope.loadStrings function is within the controller and the $scope.translateStrings gets populated but still it results in ERROR.

Comment: Thanks, I missed the priority thing in my attempts to write the custom directive earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want async loading of translation string you need to recompile ng-pluralize.

Here is a demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/0pFdk4Ac1QC5SE7JSXeJ?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, But the issue i am facing is. If I initialise $scope.translations = {'0': '0 candy for sale','one': '1 candy for sale.','other': '{} candies for sale.'};   But later If the user selects german locale, the $scope.translations stills shows english strings where it has to show german strings. I did try your approach but it doesn't work as recompiling loads the default strings(en-us)

Comment: I was trying out a custom directive too, but it was the priority attribute which never allowed my directive to be called before the builtin one. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

When the `<ng-pluralize>` element is first linked, `translateStrings` is unset. Try putting it into the `$scope` in a controller's constructor instead of on keypress.

**Update**:

Here's an example with a controller:

```
<script>
  // The controller will be injected with a new scope for your element.
  var TranslationController = function($scope) {
    // This is your code from your example. This assumes there's a global
    // 'userLocale' variable.
    if (userLocale == "en-us"){
      $scope.translateStrings = 
      {'0': '0 candy for sale','one': '1 candy for sale.','other': '{} candies for sale.'} ;
      debugger;
    }
    else if (userLocale == "de-de"){
      $scope.translateStrings = {'0': '0 Süßigkeiten ausgewählt',
      'one': '1 Süßigkeiten zum Verkauf',
      'other': '{} Süßigkeiten zum Verkauf.'
      };
      debugger;
    }
  };
</script>
```

And the HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="TranslationController">
  <input class="input-text" type="number" ng-model="candyCount" />
  <ng-pluralize count = "candyCount" when = "translateStrings" ></ng-pluralize>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly you meant w.r.t $scope

Comment: The above code is within a controller and the keypress method is within the controller.

Comment: Added an example controller.

Comment: Yes I didnt paste the complete code earlier basically what you have represented in your above snippet is what I have. The issue which I am facing is $scope.translateStrings loads with the object having translations but it is not updated to the "when" present in ng-pluralize. Thus I get a TypeError.

Comment: I'm confused, though - what you have in your example shows the initialize happening triggered on keypress. Have you tried what I showed, initializing `translateStrings` immediately on controller creation?

Comment: Yes I did try your approach and I completely understand what you meant. But the same error again. It seams that the "when" parameter in ng-pluralize loads only once during DOM initialization.

Comment: Hmm, sounds like it may not be possible to do it that way, then. `ng-switch` would work (one case per language), but it's a little ugly. You could also try a custom directive with a dynamic template.